# C# } missing in a usual if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm learning C# right now and for one of the exercises i tried creating an IF statement,but VS 2015 tells me that there's a } missing. I rewrote the script using the IF example on the MSDN website but it still says that..

I gotta write a Console application that tells if the user is whether male or not. A bool variable is in charge. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace isMale
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isMale;
            Console.WriteLine("Are you male? (Press Y to answer \"Yes\" and N to answer \"No\")");
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y) ;
            {
                isMale = true;
            } // <--- It tells meh that i have to place an } right here
            else ;
            {
                isMale = false;
            } 
            Console.WriteLine("You are male: " + isMale);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's not much but it really annoys me.

Thank you for viewing and (hopefully) helping and - Have a nice coding day!

Comment: no `;` at end of `if` line.

Comment: This is not as much a case of a missing `{` as it is a case of an extra `;`.

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: There's also an `;` after `else`.

Comment: You can not use semicolon after if or else that is syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `;` after the `if` and after the `else`. Also, in this case, the `if` can be written much simpler:

```
isMale = (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `;` after the if and the else

```
if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
{
     isMale = true;
}
else
{
     isMale = false;
}
```

Comment: OMG imma dumb person Thank you very much! XD

Comment: also remove the `;` after the `else`

Comment: People who down-voted . Is there a specific rule on stackOverflow that we should not answer a question with typos ? Please Show that rule if it is stated somewhere.